# How do i save/show manytomany field in select option field

Tags: python, jquery, django, bootstrap-4

I am working on a project where users can upload a post, edit a post and tag other users. I was able to implement upload post, edit and tag users (I implemented tag users with jquery ui). When i want to edit a post i have already tagged users on, i do not get the names of the users on select option field, instead it shows empty. How do i save/show users already tagged users from manytomany field in select option field in template. I will attach images to my question for clarity.

These are the users i tagged on my post, showing in manytomany field:

[image]

This image below is what i want, when i want to edit my post, let all tagged users of that post be shown in select option field:

[image]

Views.py:

```
def update_post_view(request, id):
    #update post
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    edit_form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if edit_form.is_valid():
            edit_form.save()   

            return redirect('site:comments', id=id)
    else:
        edit_form = PostForm(instance=post)

    #Tag username dropdown in form
    tag_list_users = User.objects.all()

    context = {
        'edit_form': edit_form,
        'post':post,
        'tag_list_users': tag_list_users,
    }
    return render(request, 'update_post.html', context)
```

Template:

```
  <label for="id_tag_someone">Tag someone:</label><br>
  <select name="tag_someone" id="id_tag_someone" multiple="" class="chosen w-100">
  {% for user in tag_list_users %}
  <option value="{{user.pk}}">{{user}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.chosen').chosen();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by adding code to my views and template:

Views.py

```
#tagged_users is a related_name to tag someone in Model
tagged_user = User.objects.filter(tagged_users=post)
```

Template

```
<label for="id_tag_someone">Tag someone:</label><br>
<select name="tag_someone" id="id_tag_someone" multiple="" class="chosen w-100">
{% for user in tagged_users %}
<option value="{{user.pk}}">{{user}}</option>
{% endfor %}
{% for user in tag_list_users %}
<option value="{{user.pk}}">{{user}}</option>
{% endfor %}
 </select>
```